# Python: how to define a 2D array by comprehension by using function?

Tags: python

I want to define a 2D (numpy) array such that ***cell(row,col) == row+col*** (or any other function of those 2 variables: row and column)

I'm looking for a functional solution, and my hope is that would not use any memory and that the resulting construct could be passed to any standard array manipulation function (matrix mult...)

Something doable in C++ with template metaprogramming.

Comment: When you say "that would not use any memory", you mean the array would not use any memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.fromfunction(function, shape)`. From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html%):

> Construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate.
>
> The resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate
>   (x, y, z).

So, for your case:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i+j, (6,6))
>>> print arr
[[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.]
 [  2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.]
 [  5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]]
```

(Of course, this does use memory -- there isn't a way to have a function which acts as if it's a numpy array but isn't actually in memory. However, for a somewhat similar case, see the `memmap` numpy class, which accesses a file stored on disk as a numpy array --  [docs here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).)

Comment: i thought about subclassing the numpy array class and defining the getelement() method properly - such a method should effectively consumes almost zero bytes - i dropped the idea because i am not confortable enough with numpy - thanks for your answer

Comment: I think such a subclass wouldn't work (or at least it wouldn't be efficient) -- numpy relies on being able to efficiently access memory locations in order to get large increases in speed. But perhaps you should look up memmap -- see the revision above.